# possible to pass URL parameter to visualforce component on lightning page

Tags: lightning, url

I have a lighting page in a lightning community(overriding a record detail page). The lighting page contains a Visualforce Page Component. The visualforce page receives the `recordID` but I'm also trying to pass an additional URL parameter, but I'm unable to.

Example:
`https://qa-companyname.cs21.force.com/s/customobj/a4im00000006247AAA?param1=test` The visualforce page controller `ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('retURL')` is coming up blank. Has anyone accomplished something like this before?

Comment: you cant use that method with embedded vf pages in lighting communities (to my knowledge) - you probably want to cehck [Communicating between Lightning Components and Visualforce Pages](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2017/01/lightning-visualforce-communication.html)

Comment: @glls well `ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');` works but the component seems to specifically allow for passing {!recordId}, wasn't sure if there was a way to piggyback off that

Comment: yes - it does work for ID, but not custom url parameters, and this is only for record pages

Comment: I don't know why you marked my question as a duplicate, that question is asking how to get the record ID which I am getting just fine.

Comment: Oops, i got mixed up with the post - its the other way around - sry

Comment: Well - anyways, there is another post that comes down to the same (what you are asking, which involves what i posted in the first comment)

Answer (score 0):

For those who are still looking for a way to do this. I have a salesforce Experience site that has a VisualForce page on it. The VisualForce page is dependent on URL parameters. This is how I retrieved the URL parameter for the site.

```
let url = (window.location != window.parent.location)
            ? document.referrer
            : document.location.href;
console.log({url});
const queryString = url.split('?')[1];
console.log({queryString});
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
console.log({urlParams});
const sfAccountId = urlParams.get("accountId");
console.log({sfAccountId});
```