# Label translation not working in Salesforce communities

Tags: visualforce, lightning, community, translation

I have a VF page which has lots of custom labels to deal with multi-lingual business use case. Language is passed from the URL of the page.

```
<DomainName>/apex/<PageName>?language=en_US
<DomainName>/apex/<PageName>?language=fr

<apex:page language="{!CurrentPage.parameters.language}">
</apex:page>
```

This is working fine.

Now I want to add this VF page to salesforce communities and translations are not working.

community URL is something like this:

```
<domainName>/s/Home?language=en_US

<domainName>/s/Home?language=fr
```

I am confused about why is language not picked from URL. How can Page be translated into Lightning communities?

Comment: I think you are having the same issue as stated here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/257227/possible-to-pass-url-parameter-to-visualforce-component-on-lightning-page

Answer (score 2):

you missed '$' character. If you change the code to this one, It will work`<apex:page language="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.language}"> </apex:page>`