# custom labels inside custom community login page

Tags: community, customlabel

I have created a custom login visualforce page for my community. I also created couple of custom labels on that page. When I am switching the language the translation are not coming up it is showing english only.

I have added the translation.

Any suggestion what I am missing?

Comment: Appears to be similar to this post https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/283942/label-translation-not-working-in-salesforce-communities

Comment: Also, recommend checking this known Issue - https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000001BtfQAE

Answer (score 0):

Hey I found the solution. Get the language code from startURL into a variable. and use it in the login visualforce page.

<apex:page language="{!langCode}">
</apex:page>